# ctypes save a structure within another structure to a file

Tags: python, python-3.x, struct, structure, ctypes

I want to save many structures within other structures in a file with ctypes but it doesn't work, Structures within another structure are not saved in a file. Only the "root" structure remains saved in the file.

```py
import ctypes


class A(ctypes.Structure):
    _pack_ = 1
    _fields_ = [("x", ctypes.c_char * 15)]

A._fields_.append(("y", A))

with open("test.struct", "wb+") as f:
    root = A(h := b"Hello")
    root.y = A(b"hi")
    f.write(root.y)
    f.write(root)


with open("test.struct", "rb+") as f:
    b = A()
    f.readinto(b)
    z = b
    o = 0
    print(b.x)
    o += 1
    print(o, z.x)
    z = z.y
```

How can I save structures within structures to a file with ctypes?

Python: 3.10 - Linux

Comment: What should the outcome of this code be? Also, as a general rule, a structure can't contain itself.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue here is defining incomplete structures. Once the *_fields_* attribute is set, it shouldn't be changed. For more details , check [[Python.Docs]: ctypes - Incomplete Types](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#incomplete-types). 
Also the code has another flaw: attempting to define a structure within itself. That's not possible, in these cases pointers should be used.

I modified your code a bit.

*code00.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import ctypes as ct
import sys


class A(ct.Structure):
    _pack_ = 1
    _fields_ = [
        ("x", ct.c_char * 15)
    ]

A._fields_.append(("y", A))


class B(ct.Structure):
    _pack_ = 1

B._fields_ = (
    ("x", ct.c_char * 15),
    ("y", A),
)


def main(*argv):
    if len(sys.argv) > 1:
        TestStruct = B
    else:
        TestStruct = A

    file_name = "test.struct"

    with open(file_name, "wb+") as f:
        root = TestStruct(h:=b"Hello")
        root.y = A(b"hi")
        f.write(root)

    with open(file_name, "rb+") as f:
        b = TestStruct()
        f.readinto(b)
        print(b.x)
        print(b.y.x)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {:s} {:03d}bit on {:s}\n".format(" ".join(elem.strip() for elem in sys.version.split("\n")),
                                                   64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32, sys.platform))
    rc = main(*sys.argv[1:])
    print("\nDone.")
    sys.exit(rc)
```

**Output**:

> ```bat
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q070269014]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.08.07_test0\Scripts\python.exe" code00.py
> Python 3.8.7 (tags/v3.8.7:6503f05, Dec 21 2020, 17:59:51) [MSC v.1928 64 bit (AMD64)] 064bit on win32
>
> b'Hello'
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "code00.py", line 47, in <module>
>     rc = main(*sys.argv[1:])
>   File "code00.py", line 41, in main
>     print(b.y.x)
> AttributeError: 'A' object has no attribute 'y'
>
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q070269014]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.08.07_test0\Scripts\python.exe" code00.py dummy
> Python 3.8.7 (tags/v3.8.7:6503f05, Dec 21 2020, 17:59:51) [MSC v.1928 64 bit (AMD64)] 064bit on win32
>
> b'Hello'
> b'hi'
>
> Done.
> ```

Comment: `AttributeError: 'A' object has no attribute 'y'`

Comment: Yes exactly. If you look, I got the same error when I ran it without arguments (it was a reproduction your scenario).

Comment: @KapesoftFx: if I think better, what was your (last) comment about?

Comment: A > B > A > B the last sequence does not work
           ______

Comment: I still don't get it. The code I posted works as it should. *A* is not supposed to work since in not defined the right way. I added *B* as an example.

Comment: First add TestStruct then A then TestStruct then A and so on, only 2 structures are saved.

Comment: Add to what? Please edit your question adding this scenario.